# POST image blob to Facebook using Graph API

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas

This is a very popular question and has an overwhelming **zero** answers on the internet.

I have a canvas translated into a blob that I want to post it to Facebook.

How do I achieve this, concisely?

Here's what I've worked out so far:

```
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")

    function shareOnFacebook() {

        myCanvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          var form = new FormData();
          form.append('newFlagPic', blob, '.png');
          console.log(form)
          FB.api(
              "/me/photos",
              "POST",
              {
                  "source": form
              },
              function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                  console.log("Success bud")
                }
              }
          );             
        });
    };
```

I find it absolutely bonkers that fb does not provide a code sample of this, as it is clearly such a frequent use case. I've been reading different answers for the past 5 hours and not a single one of them addresses the fb way of doing this.

Comment: Not sure this is the issue but the third parameter of FormData used with blob or File is the filename, not the file extension.

Comment: also `canvas.toBlob()` is currently only supported by Firefox

Comment: There is a library called canvas-toBlod.js that does the work but I am trying to achieve the same thing without success so far.